# problem to upload PDF file with laravel Connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.8

I am trying a simple file upload. I am using PHP 7.2.19, with Laravel 5.8, this problem happens with PDF files only!

```
php ini :
memory_limit = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
max_input_time = 600
max_execution_time = 300
```

**I changed:** 
`max_input_time` from 60 to 600 & `max_execution_time` from 30 to 300

**HTML code:**

```
 <form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="POST" action="{{route('brochure.update')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="commentForm">
 @csrf()@method('POST')
    <input type="file" name="brochure_file" class="default" value="{{old('brochure_file')}}" />
 </form>
```

**PHP code:**

```
public function brochureUpdate(Request $request)
{       
        dd($request->brochure_file);
}



RuntimeException
stream_socket_sendto(): Connection refused
```

Comment: try to replace `@csrf()` to `@csrf`.

Comment: you have to chmod 777 the folder storage

Comment: commonly , it's the **storage/app/public directory**

Comment: this is problem happen with PDF file only

Comment: this type of problem is mostly related to 'upload_max_filesize' or 'max_input_time' and as you are saying you changed it, so are sure you changed it in right php.ini and restarted the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File size is bigger than max size in `php.ini` file.

Try to view `phpinfo` from method you take action to upload file
as there is another `php.ini` file in `cli` folder

Comment: I realized your answer 
after i use phpinfo() in my method i founded another php.ini details of my Apache so i edited php.ini in cli folder and it works now,
thank you so much.